# How to find standard deviation error bound from variance error bound

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

I'm working on a robotics problem where I'm keeping state in 3D. The state has an error bound described by a covariance matrix I'm keeping internally. A cool property of matrices is that you can take their dot product with (in 2D)

$$[cos(t) \ sin(t)]^T, \ t \in [0, 2\pi)$$

or (in 3D)

$$ [sin(\phi)cos(\theta) \ \ sin(\phi)sin(\theta) \ \ cos(\phi)]^T, \ \phi \in [0, \pi), \ \theta \in [0, 2\pi)$$

to plot an ellipse (or ellipsoid) which neatly shows how they warp a circle (or sphere). For covariance matrices this corresponds to a notion about how uncertain your state estimate is in various directions.

Right now my ellipses are showing *variance*, because they're from the covariance matrix, but I actually would like to plot ellipses to show *standard deviation*. My question is: How can I calculate the "co-standard-deviations" matrix from the covariance matrix?

I've tried just taking a matrix square root (and also an element-wise square root), but the ellipse ends up skewed.

[image]

I know this can't be right, because the spatial directions along which my sensors have maximum uncertainty should be the same, whether I'm showing standard deviation or variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ellipsoid I want can be expressed as

$$ \{x | x^TP^{-1}x = 1 \} $$

where $P$ is a covariance matrix and $x$ is a vector/point. This is all the points on the boundary of an ellipsoid with principal axes along the eigenvectors of $P$, with length equal to the square roots of the corresponding eigenvalues. [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXAxi7H98T8&t=982s)

But what I'm really looking for to do my visualization is a matrix $A$, such that $A \cdot spheroid$ = this ellipsoid, whereas before I was doing $P \cdot spheroid$ = variance ellipsoid.

The answer turns out to be that you want the matrix $A \ s.t. AA^T = P$. I was missing the transpose!

Here are a few different proofs to solidify the intuition:

If $P$ is positive semidefinite and symmetric, as it must be if it's a covariance matrix, then it is diagonalizable as $P = VDV^{-1}$, where $V$ holds the eigenvectors and $D$ is a diagonal matrix holding eigenvalues.

If we choose unit length eigenvectors, noting that eigenvectors are orthogonal for a symmetric matrix, then $V$ is an orthonormal matrix, and $V^{-1} = V^T$.

Next, we note that because $D$ is diagonal, we can split it apart really easily as $D = D_{\sqrt{}}D_{\sqrt{}}$, where $D_{\sqrt{}}$ holds the square root of the eigenvalues on its diagonal. Once again, this will work because $P$ doesn't have any negative eigenvalues by property of being symmetric positive semidefinite.

Putting it all together we get

$$ P = VD_{\sqrt{}}D_{\sqrt{}}V^T = (VD_{\sqrt{}}) (D_{\sqrt{}}V^T) = (VD_{\sqrt{}})(VD_{\sqrt{}}^T)^T = (VD_{\sqrt{}})(VD_{\sqrt{}})^T = AA^T$$

So I can find $A$ with a simple eigenvalue-and-vector decomposition of $P$. Note $A$ is no longer symmetric, so I couldn't repeat this process recursively.

Next, find $P^{-1}$:

$$ P = VDV^T \rightarrow P^{-1}P = P^{-1}VDV^T \rightarrow I = P^{-1}VDV^T$$
and now start right multiplying by inverses
$$ \rightarrow V = P^{-1}VD \rightarrow VD^{-1}V^T = P^{-1} $$

Next, use this $A$ in the constraint of the ellipse we want:

We're going to take a whole bunch of $VD_{\sqrt{}} \cdot spheroid\ point$ to get our $x$s that satisfy the constraint. Let's call an spheroid point $s$. The constraint now becomes:

$$ (VD_{\sqrt{}}s)^T P^{-1} (VD_{\sqrt{}}s) = 1 $$

Is this true?

$$ \rightarrow (VD_{\sqrt{}}s)^T VD^{-1}V^T (VD_{\sqrt{}}s) $$
$$ = s^T(VD_{\sqrt{}})^T VD^{-1}V^T (VD_{\sqrt{}}s) $$
$$ = s^TD_{\sqrt{}}^T V^T VD^{-1}V^T VD_{\sqrt{}}s $$
$$ = s^TD_{\sqrt{}} V^{-1} VD^{-1}V^{-1} VD_{\sqrt{}}s $$
$$ = s^TD_{\sqrt{}} D^{-1} D_{\sqrt{}}s $$
$$ = s^Ts = 1$$

the last because any point on the spheroid has magnitude 1, so its dot product with itself will be 1.

Plotting all $x = VD_{\sqrt{}}s$, I see ellipses now align!
[image]

One last proof to really solidify why this is:

$V$ is orthonormal, so it's a rotation matrix. So for the variance case we first rotate our spheroid with $V^T$ to recover the same spheroid, then scale by $D$, then rotate that ellipsoid by $V$. And in the standard deviation case, we scale the spheroid by $D_{\sqrt{}}$ and the rotate that sqrts-scaled ellipsoid by $V$.

And now we see the answer to [this puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXAxi7H98T8&t=1096s) to make $A$ symmetric again: Use $Q = V^T$, so $A = VD_{\sqrt{}}V^T$. This extra rotation won't affect the rotation of the final ellipsoid, because, as in the variance case, it's applied to a spheroid and just returns the same spheroid.